# Indexing and quering many to many associations using hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am having users and contacts and a m-m between user and contacts showing which user is following which contact

I want to index contacts and query them as follows

List all contacts a user is following. List all contacts a user is following created by another user.

```
UserContacts have the following fields
id
User user;
Contact contact;

User
id
name
emailid
Set<UserContacts> userContacts;

Contacts
id
Address address;
User createdBy;
Set<UserContacts> userContacts;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use @IndexedEmbedded - http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#search-mapping-associated. The details would depend on your model and usecase.

Comment: Thanks Hardy! I could use @IndexEmbedded I could get my list of contacts.

Comment: I have another use case, I am having an Activity Entity I need to fetch all the activities of contacts that a user is following, in this case there are two different indexes for contacts and activities,how to have a type of join query ie get all the contacts and then fetch the activities of these contacts using hibernate search?

Comment: This sounds like another question. It depends all on your actual model and how you index it. Generally there is no join functionality available in Search. You need to index all you need for type you are targeting.